# Show/Hid column based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to Hid and show column based on the cell value, if the cell value is =0 it will hid the column and if the cell value <0 then it should show the column. i tried using the below code where am i wrong?

Thank you

```vb
Sub Hidecolumnbasedoncellvalue()
Dim p As Range

    For Each p In Range("E17:AB17").Cells
        If p.Value = "0" Then
            p.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        If p.Value < 0 Then
            p.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
       
       End If
    Next p
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Sub Hidecolumnbasedoncellvalue() 
    Dim p As Range, v
    
    Application.Screenupdating = False 'faster...
    For Each p In Range("E17:AB17").Cells
        v = p.Value
        If Not IsError(v) Then 'ignore any error values
            If Len(v) > 0 Then '...or empty cells
                If v = 0 Then
                    p.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                ElseIf v > 0 Then
                    p.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                End if
            End If
        End If 'not error
    Next p
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, as the cell value will only be either =0  or <0

Comment: I have tried using the code, its working when the cell value is =0, but when it is <0 it is not functioning (column remains hidden)

Comment: I did a small adjustment, and it worked :)

Comment: Sub Hidecolumnbasedoncellvalue()
    Dim p As Range, v
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'faster...
    For Each p In Range("E17:AB17").Cells
        v = p.Value
        If Len(v) > 0 And Not IsError(v) Then
            If v = 0 Then
                p.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            ElseIf v > 0 Then
                p.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            End If
        End If
    Next p
End Sub

Comment: Thanks @chrisneilsen: fixed - that's what I get for coding in the browser...

Comment: You had "and if the cell value <0 then it should show the column" in your question: sounds like that was *not* what you wanted?

Comment: @Time Williams, yup, it was supposed to be >0. Thanks again for the quick help